# How to receive back information for specific indexed items in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, api, command-line-interface, net-http

I have a CLI I'm trying to build with API data and I am unable to get my indexed individual episodes to print details such as episode title, description, writer, director and air date. I'm currently just trying to get title and description to work right now but keep running into errors or getting all the episodes descriptions and titles to print at once. Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong?

Let me say I'm currently learning to code and this is my first CLI - please be kind!

Here is the method I'm working on

```
 def print_details(episode)
    puts "here are some details"
    puts EpisodeIndex::API.new.titles(episode.to_i)
    puts EpisodeIndex::API.new.description(episode.to_i)
 
  end
```

and then this is the error I'm getting (I wanted to have my main menu in there too so you could see where I'm going from. I am able to get the menu to list and I want to type "2" to get info about "2. Diversity Day" however I am getting an error...

```
Hello, friend!
Here are some episodes from 'The Office'
1. Pilot
2. Diversity Day
3. Health Care
4. The Alliance
5. Basketball
6. Hot Girl
7. The Dundies
8. Sexual Harassment
9. Office Olympics
10. The Fire
11. Halloween
12. The Fight
13. The Client
14. Performance Review
15. E-Mail Surveillance
16. Christmas Party
17. Booze Cruise
18. The Injury
19. The Secret
20. The Carpet
21. Boys and Girls
22. Valentine's Day
23. Dwight's Speech
24. Take Your Daughter to Work Day
25. Michael's Birthday
26. Drug Testing
27. Conflict Resolution
28. Casino Night

Type the episode number you want more information on.
2
here ae some details
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from bin/office_cli:5:in `<main>'
    3: from /Users/jocelynpeters/Development/code/office_cli/lib/cli.rb:11:in `run'
    2: from /Users/jocelynpeters/Development/code/office_cli/lib/cli.rb:27:in `list_menu'
    1: from /Users/jocelynpeters/Development/code/office_cli/lib/cli.rb:47:in `print_details'
/Users/jocelynpeters/Development/code/office_cli/lib/api.rb:11:in `titles': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError)
```

I'm not sure if this is important but here's the API I'm using too: https://www.officeapi.dev/api/episodes/

this is part of my API class

```
  
      def titles
        uri = URI.parse(@url)
        response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)

        data = JSON.parse(response)
        data["data"].map do |episode|
        Episode.new(episode)
            episode["title"]
            
        end
```

Comment: Like the error message tells you: In your `print_details` you try to read from the method or variable `input` but that variable or method does not exist. What do you expect `input` to return? Where and how did you define it?

Comment: So I did a little more research and decided maybe I need to change to (episode.to_i). I've changed the EpisodeIndex::API.new.titles.find(input.to_i) to EpisodeIndex::API.new.titles(episode.to_i). I'm now getting an argument error.

Comment: You need to show your code. We cannot know what `episode` actually is. Is it an integer? A complex model? What do the methods of your class actually do?

Comment: @spickermann ahh, my apologies. I've updated the question with more code. The methods of my CLI class are for puts and prints statements and user inputs. My API class is for grabbing info from my API and I also have an episode class  that hashes out my data.

Comment: Can you show your `Episode` class? I think your error is because of the `Episode.new(episode)` line. Does your `initialize` method take an argument?

Comment: @maxpleaner I've changed a few things around and I think I got it to kind of work but I am still coming across a issue where the method returns a bunch of ```Type the episode number you want more information on.
2
here ae some details
#<EpisodeIndex::Episode:0x00007fe14494eb20>
#<EpisodeIndex::Episode:0x00007fe14494c280>
#<EpisodeIndex::Episode:0x00007fe144957310>```.  Would it be inappropriate to post the github link to show you?

Comment: "Inappropriate" is not the right word ... its unnecessary. You can edit your question to include more relevant code. Looking at your output, I am sure you are passing something other than a string to `puts` ...

Answer (score 2):

You really don't need separate methods and API calls here for each attribute of the episodes. Instead just fetch the API data and store it a an array or a hash.

```
class Episode
  attribute_accessor :title
  attribute_accessor :description

  def initialize(**attributes)
    @title = attributes["title"]
    @description = attributes["description"]
  end
end
```

```
module APIClient
  def self.fetch
    uri = URI.parse("https://www.officeapi.dev/api/episodes")
    response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    JSON.parse(response)["data"].map do |raw|
      Episode.new(raw)
    end
  end
end
```

```
class CLI
  def initialize(episodes)
    # creates a hash with 1 indexed keys
    @episodes = Hash[(1..episodes.length).zip(episodes)]
  end

  def run
    puts "Hello, friend!"
    puts "Here are some episodes from 'The Office'"
    list
    puts "Type the episode number you want more information on. Or leave blank to exit"
    get_episode_number
  end

  private

  def list
    @episodes.each do |index, episode|
      puts "#{index}. #{episode.title}"
    end
  end

  def get_episode_number
    while input = gets.chomp
      break if input == ""
      if @episodes[input.to_i]
        details(@episodes[input.to_i])
      else
        puts "Thats not a valid number. Please try again."
      end
    end
  end

  def details(episode)
    puts episode.description
  end
end
```

```
CLI.new(APIClient.fetch).run
```

Here we are using a hash with numbered keys to avoid having to deal with a 0 indexed array. We are then using this stored data both to show the list